# Theme in android

Tags: android, wordpress, themes, runtime-error, android-theme

I´m noob in the android programming area, and I have a big problem with changing the theme in eclipse!! The app runs nice with the predetermined theme, when I change it i did this:

1) go to the manifest > Application > select "Browse" > this theme: @android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen  (did apear at the code)

2) activity_Main > I selected the same theme but didn´t apear at the code.

thats it! and when i run it the AVD says: "The application Bola de cristal (Process com.RMapps.boladecristal) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again"

I dont know what to do! please someone has an idea? thanks in advanced!!

Excuse my english, its not my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the actual XML of the manifest.  You should see your theme under application:

```
<application
     android:theme="android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

This will apply the themem to all activities that don't explicitly override it.

In Eclipse, when viewing the activity designer, you can select themes from a dropdown and you will see the change take place in front of you but this will not actually save and compile for you.  So when you run your app, you will be a bit confused.  You need to explicitly declare the theme for an activity under that activity def in the manifest, just like you did for the application as a whole.

```
<activity
     android:theme="android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

But again, you don't need to do this if you want to use the theme that you set at the application level.

If your app is still crashing then you have another problem going on.  Perhaps the theme you are selecting isn't actually present or maybe you have another bug you didn't realize you introduced during the time of adjusting the theme

Comment: feel free to accept the answer and/or vote it up if you think it's appropriate :)